# How to linearize constraints in Gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

i'm using **Gurobi**,

I have 2 decision variables `x` and `y`, and i want to linearize some constraints, here's my code :

```py
m.addConstr( x == max(0, y) )
m.addConstr( x >= 0 )
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "linearize"?  What data structure is `x`? Does your code work or not? If not, what is the problematic behaviour you are encountering? Please revise your question along the lines of [ask], and post an [mcve]!

Comment: If the `max` part is giving you modeling troubles, please have a look at the [`gurobipy.max_`](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_max_.html) function.  If you don't succeed, please revise your question as suggested above.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming Objective Function is a minimization, and you just want to track the max value of something, say an energy peak,

If m.addConstr( x >= 0 ) is a real requirement,
then you can just set y=x, which makes no sense as x will stay non-negative by itself with no need for y

**OR**

you can use

```
m.addConstr(x>=0)
m.addConstr(x>=y)
```

and put x in the objective function with positive cost coeff. This will keep x tied to max(0,y)

ref https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2011/01/max-and-min-functions-in-mip.html

Comment: This doesn't achieve what @hungkai wants (the question is not quite clear though): Your constraints only guarantee that `x >= max(0, y)`, but the question asks for `x == max(0,y)`.